# Highlight selected table cell C# Menu

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic Menu populating from database. I have issues in highlighting the currently selected Menu, I am using ASP.net C#. Please check the code below.

HTML

```
function highlight(clMenu) {
        clMenu.id = "clMenu";
    }

<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:Table ID="tblMenu" runat="server" Width="100%">
    </asp:Table>
</form>
```

C#

```
TableRow rwMenu = new TableRow();
ConnectionCls ConObj = new ConnectionCls();
string StrQuery = "select * from Menus where isenabled=1";
ConObj.GetSqlDataTable(ref Dt, StrQuery);
if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  for (i = 0; i <= Dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    string Href = Dt.Rows[i]["url"].ToString();
    clMenu.Text = "<a Href=" + Href + ">" + Dt.Rows[i]["MenuName"] + "</a>";
    clMenu.Attributes.Add("onclick", "highlight(this)");
    rwMenu.Cells.Add(clMenu);
    tblMenu.Rows.Add(rwMenu);
  }
}
```

Everything is working perfectly except the menu onclick event. When i click on a Menu its background color i am able to change successfully, on clicking another menu its background color also changing but the previous selected menu its not clearing

CSS

```
#clMenu {
    background-color:#EE3D43;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recommend to go for CSS class attachment instead of setting DOM element's `id`; because logically there has to be unique ids to each and every DOM element. But single CSS class can be assigned to many elements though.

So please have a look at below changes:

**CSS:**

```
.clMenu {
    background-color:#EE3D43;
}
```

**Javascript code:**

```js
function highlight(domElem) {
    $(".clMenu").removeClass('clMenu'); //removing highlight class from previously clicked  menu
    $(domElem).addClass('clMenu'); //adding highlight class to currently clicked menu
}
```

---

Comment: I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I tried its not working.

cs->clMenu.Attributes.Add("onclick", "highlight(this)");
js-> function highlight(domElem) {
            var previousElem = document.getElementsByClassName("clMenu");
            previousElem.className.replace(/\bclMenu\b/, ''); //removing highlight class from previously clicked  menu

            clMenu.className += " clMenu"; //adding highlight class to currently clicked menu
        }

css->.clMenu {
    background-color:#EE3D43;
}

Comment: so sorry @NKhan. I missed small code. Could you please try with updated `function highlight` one more time...Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still not, i am getting the below error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @NKhan - do you have JQuery on your page?

Comment: Yes: I have added


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: @NKhan - please check it now. Function now uses `jQuery` class selector

Answer (score 1):

If this class are used only for this anchors only then try this

```
function highlight(clMenu){ 
    $(this).attr('id').click(function () {
       $(document).find('.anchorColor').removeClass('anchorColor');
       var aId = $(this).attr('id');
       $(this).addClass('anchorColor');
    });
}
```

and instead of doing the css with id try with class:

```css
.anchorColor {
    background-color:#EE3D43;
}
```

Comment: Getting error: Uncaught TypeError: this.attr is not a function